# Graph triangle-free and maximun degree

Tags: graph-theory

Let G=(V,E) be a graph trangle free.

a)Prove that $\Delta(G) \ge \frac{|V|}2$

b)Prove that there exists such a graph for |V|= 1,2

How would I prove this? particularly the part a)

thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $\Delta(G)$?

Comment: $\Delta(G)$ is the maximun degree of G

Comment: Do you mean $\leq$ in (1)? And are you sure you are writing (2) correctly? *Every* graph with $1$ or $2$ vertices is triangle-free.

Comment: No, I don't. So I have to try and Yes so this part was not necessary, but if you could try to |V|=3 or 4 I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

a) is false.

Consider $C_n$, the cycle of length $n$ for $n\geq 5$.  Note $C_n$ is $2$-regular (and triangle free), so $\Delta(C_n)=2$.  Hence, there can be no vertex with degree $$\geq \frac{n}{2}\geq\frac {5}{2}=2.5.$$